# White pure CSS triangle bug on Firefox 6 Windows

Tags: html, css, firefox

http://jsfiddle.net/pixelfreak/Eq246/

Notice the gray border on the white triangle. This only happens on FF 6 Windows (I did not test on older FF version)

Is there a fix to this? It looks like bad anti-aliasing or something.

Comment: To be honest, I don't see a gray border. FF 6 on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: I had the exact same problem, see the solution provided to me here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9393354/strange-behavior-with-borders-on-firefox-10-on-windows

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Give it a try with this:

```
border-style: outset;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KDREU/

## edit

Looks like if you put outset on one of the 4 border styles you can use colors other than white and not have them lightened.

```
/* This works for an orange down arrow that I'm using. */
border-style: solid outset solid solid;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fEKrE/1/

Comment: Note that depending on the direction the triangle is pointing to you'd have to use `inset` instead of `outset`.

Answer (score 1):

It happens on FF6 on Linux too. It's going to be an artifact from antialiasing the diagonal line. AFAIK, there isn't a way around this other than to use an image.

Comment: I think if Firefox used alpha-antialiasing (aAA? :-P) then the grey line would disappear, but it uses RGB AA unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

fixed with

```
border-style: solid dashed solid solid;
```

tested on firefox 19.0.2, opera 12.04, chromium 25.0.1359.0