# Strange behavior with borders on Firefox 10 on windows

Tags: css, windows, firefox

I'm trying to create arrows using borders but FF10 on win7 doesn't want to play ball.

It adds a 1px border around my border.

Here is a JSFiddle with a minimal example:
http://jsfiddle.net/5jjVb/1/

It doesn't matter what color the border I set has, the extra border is always the same color.

For those of you not on FF or on window 7 here is a screenshot:

[image: They put a border around my border so I can have an arrow in my arrow]

And here is the same arrow in FF on OS X:

[image: No extra border]

I could always change the color of the arrow to the same color as the extra border but that doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bug. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=646053

And here is workout to tackle this issue. http://jsfiddle.net/5jjVb/3/

Comment: Awesome! But this gives me another problem, the border is antialiased. Know any way of disabling this?

Comment: Yeah, the border is antialiased but only on FF on windows

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
div {
    border: 30px solid transparent;
    border-left-color: #EEE;
    -moz-border-left-colors: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `rgba()` instead of `transparent` for transparency.For more check my this answer

[CSS Transparent Border Problem In Firefox 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225284/css-transparent-border-problem-in-firefox-4/6225443#6225443)

Comment: Awesome! But this gives me another problem, the border is antialiased. Know any way of disabling this?